# Check if Angular Observable has data or not

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I make an API call like the below:

```
public getAllLocations(): Observable<any>
{                                                                   
  location = https://v/locations.pipe(timeout(180000));
  return location;
}
```

This API `getAllLocations()` is called multiple times in different `components`.  So to avoid multiple API calls, I want to check if this `Observable` has value or not.

If the value is not present, I will call the API. Otherwise, I will return to the location.

I am unsure how we can check the observable data without subscribing

I am new to Angular. Please suggest a good way to implement this

Comment: Sounds like you want to cache the result forever. In this case use [shareReplay](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/shareReplay)

Comment: This didn't work because of this scenario. I have 2 pages (Home Page, Location Page). In both the pages I'm calling this api. When the application loads, initially it calls Home Page where I have called the API  getAllLocations(). In Location Page I am calling with Location variable(where I have cached the result) . If i go back to home page, its again calling the api, since I have called getAllLocations().

Answer (score 0):

As far as my understanding of Angular you cannot check the value of data of subscription without `subscribe` method. Method `subscribe` is the one which emits the API call when ever the relevant function is called.

If you need to check the data values without the subscription being affected you can use `tap` and `do` operators.

Comment: How can we use tap in this case? You mean in an if condition? Can you please provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to check for returned values without subscribing to the observable. you can use `takeWhile` operator to check whether the expected result is returned from your API. in your case you can check whether the API return a non-nullable value and continue if the value is present. `takeWhile` will automatically unsubscribe if the condition is not fulfilled.

for an example

```
source$
 .pipe(takeWhile(val => val !== null)
 .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```